# Angular: Why date is wrapped in double quote

Tags: angularjs

I am learning angular. So tried a custom filter which will return date in utc format. Code works, but double quote comes in output. what mistake I've made?

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.today = new Date();
});

app.filter('getUtcDate', [
  function() {
    return function(input) {
      return input;
    };
  }
]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
    <p>Date = {{ today | getUtcDate }}</p>
  </div>
  <p>The date filter formats a date object to a readable format.</p>
</body>
```

### Output

**Date = `"2017-04-27T09:36:09.166Z"`**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could remove your ""

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">

<p>Date = {{ today | getUtcDate }}</p>

var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.today = new Date();
});

app.filter('getUtcDate', [
    function() {
    debugger;
        return function(input) {
            return input.toUTCString();
        };
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is the expected behaviour as per

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14027

*Since you are using interpolation ({{...}}).
$interpolate must return a string and thus tries to stringify non-string values, by converting them to JSON.*

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you do it for learning or create a real filter, but AngularJS already provide a [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), that can include the timezone.

The synthax is: `{{yourDate | date: dateFormat : timezone}}`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
    <p>Date = {{today | date:'MMM d, y H:mm:ss' : 'UTC'}}</p>
</div>

<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.today = new Date();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The PO want UTC Time

Comment: i am learning angular. so tried to write and test a filter but stuck what i mention here.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter it in controller itself as like below,

```
$scope.today = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy', 'UTC');
```

Note: Don't forget to inject $filter into your controller

Comment: how to call my custom filter in code like $filter(). please add few line here for guidance if possible. thanks

Comment: you can use it as like $filter('customFilter')(date); in your controller code.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your date to a string first to get rid of the quotes:

```
app.filter('getUtcDate', [
function() {
    return function(input) {
        return input.toString();
    };
}]);
```

Comment: there is little difference between your and my code. you used .toString() and i did not. why double quote will come if i do not use .toString()  in my custom filter ? please explain if u know the reason.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS has evolved over time and answers to this are getting shorter compared previously.

Filter is not really required right now. Just convert your date to UTCString.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('datCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.today = new Date().toUTCString();
});
```

While HTML

```
<body>
 <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="datCtrl">
  <p>Date = {{today}}</p>
 </div>
 <p>The date filter formats a date object to a readable format.</p>
</body>
```

Hope this helps. Tested with AngularJS 1.7+